# userform vlookup without using application.vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, userform

I am currently trying to create a userform that would call the matching values of column B,C,D with column A value. In order to show value of column B, C and D into textbox2, textbox3 and textbox4 then I have to put the value of column A to textbox1. My data in my sheet is indefinite so as much as possible I don't want to use `application.vlookup`. I've used a code for this matter that my colleague provided me which is actually working on some of the userforms that I created. However, as I use it now it just won't work.

```
Private Sub Textbox1_AfterUpdate()

If Textbox1.Value = "" Then

Textbox2 = ""
Textbox3 = ""
Textbox4 = ""
Exit Sub

Else

x = 2
Do Until Sheet2.Cells(x, "A") = Textbox1.Value
If Sheet2.Cells(x, "C").Value = "" Then
Textbox2 = ""
Textbox3 = ""
Textbox4 = ""
Exit Sub
End If

x = x + 1
Loop

Textbox2 = Sheet2.Cells(x, "B")
Textbox3 = Sheet2.Cells(x, "C")
Textbox4 = Sheet2.Cells(x, "D")
End If

End Sub
```

I hope you can look into this, point out what is wrong and suggest any corrections.

Thank you!

Comment: Built-in functions like Vlookup will always be faster than looping through the rows and comparing values. What makes you think Vlookup will not be fast enough?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not really good at this. I used vlookup before but it always requires me to create a name for the column of my lookup values in my spreadsheet and if my new data is exceeds the number of my previous data then I have to redo range of the name as the lookup values. Could you suggest any solution or a better vlookup codes?

Comment: I wonder what code it was using vlookup that didn't work

Comment: @PatricK Vlookup works. I just don't want to update name range on the spreadsheet from time to time. Is it possible to use vlookup without creating a name range. I'm sorry.. I'm really not good at this.

Comment: The named range can be dynamic with builtin formulas which can involve other named range. Show us dummy data screenshot and we can help that too.

Comment: You may want to go with dictionaries. Try it

Comment: Vlookup can be used on whole columns. Even without using whole columns, defining a range for the lookup should be trivial compared to trying to write an alternative to Vlookup from scratch with VBA. Maybe you can step back from particular techniques and functions and explain the bigger picture? What determines the lookup range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You objections to `VLookup`are not valid.  There is no need to *create a name for the column of my lookup* nor to *redo range of the name as the lookup values*

Just do the search on the whole column.

That said, `Application.Match` is actually more useful in this case

Your code, refactored

```
Private Sub Textbox1_AfterUpdate()
    Dim x As Variant
    If Textbox1.Value <> vbNullString Then
        With Sheet2
            x = Application.Match(Textbox1.Value, .Columns(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(x) Then
                If .Cells(x, "C").Value <> vbNullString and x >= 2 Then
                    Textbox2 = .Cells(x, "B")
                    Textbox3 = .Cells(x, "C")
                    Textbox4 = .Cells(x, "D")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
    Textbox2 = vbNullString
    Textbox3 = vbNullString
    Textbox4 = vbNullString
End Sub
```

before adding data to TextBox1

[image: before adding data to TextBox1]

after adding data to TextBox1

[image: after adding data to TextBox1]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I tried applying it to my userform and after putting value in texbox1 it didn't do anything.

Comment: I have tested this code, it does work.  Clearly there is something else you are doing that is wrong.

Comment: Wow.. I tried to do it again this morning and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can stick with your previous code that uses `vlookup`, just change that named range a bit and add another named range as marking of top left data.

Say you have this table (offset from A1 on purpose):
[image: sample data]

Named range **`TopLeftData`** is set to **`B3`**. Then the Name **`Names`** is set to this formula `=OFFSET(TopLeftData,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!B:B)-1,2)` (you need to change "Sheet1" or had another name pointing to that column), then vlookup using the **Names** with work fine.

As long as valid data is below **TopLeftData** and no data above it, the name **Names** will work dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one :

```
   Private Sub Textbox1_AfterUpdate()


                Dim ws As Worksheet
                Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

                toFind = TextBox1.Value
                Set trouve = ws.Columns("A").Find(what:=toFind, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
                If trouve Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print "Not Found ! "
                Else
                    firstAddress = trouve.Address
                    foundRow = trouve.Row

                    TextBox2.Value = ws.Cells(foundRow, 2)
                    TextBox3.Value = ws.Cells(foundRow, 3)
                    TextBox4.Value = ws.Cells(foundRow, 4)

                End If

    End Sub
```